# How to get sum of values per id and update existing records in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, aggregate-functions

I have two tables like:

```
ID          |    TRAFFIC
fd56756     |      4398
645effa     |    567899
894fac6     |    611900
894fac6     |    567899
```

and

```
USER        |      ID         |    TRAFFIC
andrew      |    fd56756      |       0
peter       |    645effa      |       0
john        |    894fac6      |       0
```

I need to get `SUM ("TRAFFIC")` from first table AND set column traffic to the second table  where first table `ID = second` table ID. ID's from first table are not unique, and can be duplicated.
How can I do this?

Comment: Use code tags next time, no need to insert HTML spaces. Code tags are where you write your question, in the toolbar at the left and are like this `{}`.

Comment: There is no column `traffic` in your second table. Please clarify. Also, columns and values in the second table seem to be switched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table names from your later comment. Chances are, you are reporting table and column names incorrectly.

```
UPDATE users u
SET    "TRAFFIC" = sub.sum_traffic
FROM  (
   SELECT "ID", sum("TRAFFIC") AS sum_traffic
   FROM   stats.traffic
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
WHERE u."ID" = sub."ID";
```

Aside: It's unwise to use mixed-case identifiers in Postgres. Use legal, lower-case identifiers, which do not need to be double-quoted, to make your life easier. [Start by reading the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE users t2 SET t2.traffic = t1.sum_traffic FROM
 (SELECT sum(t1.traffic) t1.sum_traffic FROM stats.traffic t1)
WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: I have first table called stats.traffic with column "ID" AND "TRAFFIC" (uppercase) and second called users with "USER" , "ID" and "TRAFFIC" (uppercase). So what mean t2 and t1 ? This something like temp var ? I'm trying many times but unfortunately cannot execute query (I'm newbie, sorry) How query will looks like with my "uppercase" column names?

Comment: Modified my example to suit your case then. The t1 and t2 are aliases for the table name, just to save typing table1.xxx.